# I have a weird problem with bootstrap-vue tooltip position

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i have many pages with tables and alot of tooltips ...

the problem is that the tooltip works well in some pages

[image: it works well here]

.. but in some other pages it has a positioning problem that seems impossible to solve ...

[image: it doesn't work here]

i have tried adding the container:'body' but it didn't work .. also tried container:'#app' and the same problem still there ..
the code for the both of them is the same ..

[image: the code]

```
<a title="show" href="#" v-b-tooltip.hover.top="'Show'">
  <span class="pcoded-micon">
      <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg mx-2"></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Taking a wild guess here. If you have added padding-left to `span.pcoded-micon` then might be the issue. Replace padding-left with margin-left.

Comment: nope .. there is no padding there

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be with bootstrap and popper in Popper.js.
Try adding this to your css:

```
.tooltip { top: 0; }
```

source: [solution](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/1732)

Comment: Please give some supporting details along with the link to provide some context for your answer - for example, the issue at hand appears to be a bug that might get fixed in the future, which might be valuable information for future visitors.